# Automatic transfer of funds between exchanges

Tags: exchanges, currencies, withdrawal, arbitrage

I need to circulate money between exchanges automatically. I want to transfer cryptocurrency (BTC, LTC) between exchanges. I find that these exchanges have API calls for withdrawal options: Cryptsy, Poloniex, Bitstamp, Bittrex and Bleutrade.

Is there any other way to implement this for the exchanges which does not provide withdrawal options via API? I also want to transfer USD between exchanges. Can I implement it programmatically i.e via API?

Comment: Heya! Which exchanges do not have APIs for withdraw/deposit options (you'll need deposit too of course, if you want to circle it between exchanges).

Comment: Yeah Mathias. I need withdrawal options also

Comment: Well, if there are no API options, I think you are very limited (if it's not impossible). USD deposits are manually (afaik) because your bank probably does not support API calls.

Comment: @Mathias711 - Do you suggest any ideas to implement this?

Comment: I do not know precisely what you want, nor have I the expertise to write a full script (nor the time right now) but you can ask for a deposit address at exchange B and withdraw from exchange A to that address (all from API). That should be a very basic beginning. Then you can extent this by asking the deposit address for exchange C, and withdraw from B to C. Something like that

Comment: @Mathias711 - Incase of absence of withdrawal api call what to do? Is there any other solution to do this?

Comment: Manually? Nothing else I guess.

Comment: @Mathias711 - Yes the same also I feel

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to transfer cryptocurrencies between exchanges, but there is no way to transfer USD without withdrawing to your bank account or some kind of e-wallet first. All exchanges I've seen do not allow withdrawals to third parties.